# Record audio and show waveform react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

So I am trying to create the waveform shape in react native while recording an audio, I looked up many packages but they all need an audio url so they don't support realtime recording, I tried creating one by myself which i used a package that provides me with the decibals value when recording and then push the value to state array but it cause too many lags since I setstate every 0.5 sec.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

This package [audio-react-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-react-recorder) provides the recording interface as well as a somewhat customisable waveform. I think it's a good place to start. I used it a few times, it works quite well.

Here's a [demo](https://doppelgunner.github.io/audio-react-recorder/)

Let me know if it works out for you.

[image]

Comment: First time when you start audio it give error `Error: There seems to be an issue with your Mic`

Comment: Hello there, it really must be an error with your Mic (probably permission?). I just checked it on my end, it still works for me.

Comment: asked for react native